# React Bootstrap: triggering a Popover seems to break Dropdown components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, react-bootstrap, popper.js

I have a parent component that renders both a react-bootstrap Popover and a DropdownButton, like so.

```
const OverlayTrigger = ReactBootstrap.OverlayTrigger;
const Popover = ReactBootstrap.Popover;
const DropdownButton = ReactBootstrap.DropdownButton;
const Dropdown = ReactBootstrap.Dropdown;

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="d-flex w-50 justify-content-around">
          <OverlayTrigger
            trigger="hover"
            placement="right"
            overlay={
              <Popover id="popover-basic">
                <Popover.Title as="h3">Popover</Popover.Title>
                <Popover.Content>My Popover</Popover.Content>
              </Popover>
            }
          >
            <Button>Hover Over Me First</Button>
          </OverlayTrigger>

          <DropdownButton title="Then, Click Me Second">
            <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">This</Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Overlay</Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Won't</Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Apper</Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">After</Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Clicking</Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Popover</Dropdown.Item>
          </DropdownButton>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Issue:
Once the popover is triggered via an event, the Dropdown no longer works at all, even after the popover is dismissed. I have used both the Dropdown and DropdownButton components, and the issue persists. I have even tried changing the popover's triggering event to hover, and no luck there either.

Specs:

- React-Bootstrap 1.4.0
- React and ReactDOM 17.0.1
- Twitter Bootstrap 4.5.0

Here is a pen demonstrating the problem if you want to fiddle with it https://codepen.io/UntidyJoseph/pen/abZaZqe

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
I should also mention that both of these components come straight from the React-Bootstrap documentation, and seem to have every reason to work together.

Answer (score 1):

An update of "react-overlays" to version >= 4.1.1 fixes this problem. I simply added this specific version into my package.json file to avoid sticking to the old 2.x through dependency resolution.